# How to create a desktop pool horizon powercli

Tags: powercli

I try with this code: http://www.askaresh.com/2018/01/automating-desktop-pool-creation-using.html (the same code) but i have this error:

> New-HVPool : Failed to create Pool with error: Exception calling "ViewComposerDomainAdministrator_List" with "2"
>   argument(s): "ExceptionType : VMware.Hv.UnexpectedFault
>   ErrorMessage : Encountered unexpected error during execution
>   CauseString : java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>   CauseStackTrace : System.String[]
>   ErrorCode :
>   ErrorAttributes : "
>   At C:\psscripts\index.ps1:27 char:5
>   +     New-HVPool -spec $path
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,New-HVPool

is there another way to make a desktop pool using powercli?

Comment: What version of Horizon are you using?

Comment: @KyleRuddy horizon 7.2